# Porque o segundo WHILE não está funcionando?

Tags: php

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `teste` WHERE id='1' ";
<div class="box-header">
          <h2><?php while($d = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
                <?php echo $d["cnpj_cpf_tab_clientes"];?>
                <?php echo $d["telefone_tab_clientes"];?>                               
                <?php } ?></h2>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead><tr>
                  <th>CNPJ</th>
                  <th>Telefone</th>                   
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $dado["cnpj_cpf_tab_clientes"];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $dado["telefone_tab_clientes"];?></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <h2>Endereço</h2>
            </div>
```

Porque o segundo `while($dado..)` não me retorna nenhum resultado?

Comment: Pq o resultset já foi esgotado no primeiro while (se ele forem os mesmos)

Comment: São os mesmo. Você pode me ajudar como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Da pra fazer o while 1x adicionando os dados à um array, e então mais a frente você pode chamar eles usando um foreach nesse array novo

Comment: Entendi, vou pesquisar como usar foreach, valeu

Comment: Fiz um teste no meu banco de dados e da forma que está na minha resposta ta funcionando redondo!

Comment: @Junior se quiser um exemplo eu faço pra tu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acontece que o fetch_array "consome" todas as linhas no primeiro while, ou seja muda o ponteiro interno até o final dos dados durante o while. Dessa forma precisa retornar o ponteiro para a primeira linha colocando:

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

antes do segundo while

```
   <div class="box-header">
      <h2>
      <?php 
      $result = $con->query($consulta);
      while($d = $result->fetch_array()){ ?>
            <?php echo $d["cnpj_cpf_tab_clientes"];?>
            <?php echo $d["telefone_tab_clientes"];?>                               
            <?php } ?></h2>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead><tr>
              <th>CNPJ</th>
              <th>Telefone</th>                   
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
            mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
            while($dado = $result->fetch_array()){ ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["cnpj_cpf_tab_clientes"];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["telefone_tab_clientes"];?></td>
                        </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <h2>Endereço</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: Valeu, obrigado